# Time Machine file only showing up on one MacBook

Tags: backup, time-machine, hdd

I backed up my MacBook Air 2020 (Big Sur) to an HDD. I factory reset my MacBook Air so that it would be ready to sell. It updated itself to Catalina. I realized I forgot some important local files on my Air. I tried restoring the Air with the HDD but when I used Migration Assistant, it permanently stays in "Looking for source". On the Air's Finder, there wasn't any Time Machine backup in the HDD. I've tried to Repair on Disk Utility. On Disk Utility, it's taking up 300gb so there is something there.

I plugged into my new MacBook Pro 2021 (Monterey) and it's able to detect the Time Machine file in Finder and detect the backup in Migration Assistant.

Comment: Monterey & Catalina require different Time Machine drive formats. What OS was on the Air before you reset it & what OS is on it now?

Comment: @Tetsujin it was Big Sur on my Air when I backed up and now on my Air it's Catalina. My Pro is Monterey. The Time Machine backup isn't being detected on my Air but it is on my Pro

Comment: Big Sur was the point at which it changed. Prior to that Time machine was on HFS+, since, it's on APFS. The two are not interchangeable. You need to upgrade the Air to at least Big Sur to be able to see it. BTW - ***don't*** try to repair it, it's not 'broken'. Repairing it *might* break it, as the older OS doesn't understand the newer format, so results are unpredictable.

Comment: @Tetsujin upgrading the OS worked, thanks so much!